# С# не могу убить процесс

Tags: c#

Хочу убить процесс, но так получается что убиваются процессы в имени которых только одно слово, если два то не выходит.
К примеру:
этот процесс убивается.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Discord"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
        }
```

а вот этот нет.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("Microsoft Edge"))
            {
                process.Kill();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Черт подери, я разобрался, нужно просто имя процесса писать слитно.